# Good practices for designing REST api relations

Tags: api, rest

We currently trying to design some REST api for our webservices. We have two resources, 'record' and 'expedition'. As far as we know, a record can be associated with multiple expeditions, and an expedition can be associated with one record (but not necessarily).

When we create an expedition, and we want to "attach" it to a record, we have come to two solutions :

1. `POST /expeditions?recordId=xxx`
2. `POST /records/xxx/expeditions`
   and a `POST /expeditions` WS to create expeditions independently.

My colleague suggested the first approach, but I found the second the most usual way to do so. I have not found articles on the web presenting the first approach as a good or bad design.

So, which solution is the good one for you ? Which kind of consideration can help us to choose ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Which kind of consideration can help us to choose ?

Think about [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

HTTP is about [document transfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).  We obtain information from the server by asking for a copy of a document; that request might be handled by the server itself, or it might be handled by a cache that has a valid copy of the document.

We send information to a server by proposing edits to documents - POST being the most common method used to do that (via HTML forms).

When an edit is successful, it follows that the previously cached copies of the document are out of date, and we would really prefer that they be replaced by the updated copy.

General purpose cache invalidation is kind of limited; in particular, it doesn't support *arbitrary* invalidation of documents.  Only the target-uri, Location, and Content-Location are invalidated.

Therefore, when we are designing our resource interactions, we want to consider this limitation.

That usually means that the request that we use to change a document should have the same target-uri as the request to read that same document.

(Yes, that means that if we are going to have different kinds of edits to the document, all of the different edits share the same target-uri, and we disambiguate the edit by looking at other parts of the request -- for instance by parsing the body.)

---

> POST /records/xxx/expeditions and a POST /expeditions WS to create expeditions independently.

That's not required - the server is permitted to apply changes to more than one document; HTTP constrains the meaning of the request, but does not constrain the effects.

That said, general purpose caches won't magically know that both documents have been edited.  To some degree, part of what you are choosing in your design is which document needs to be refreshed *now*, and which ones can be out of date for a time (typically until the cached representation reaches its max age).

---

For the *special case* where your response to the successful edit is going to be a copy of the updated representation of the resource, you have a little bit more freedom, because use can use the [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2) header to identify which document we are returning in the response, and that header is automatically invalidated.

```
POST /foo/bar

...
```

```
200 OK
Content-Location: /foo
```

In this sequence, general purpose headers will invalidated their cached copies of both `/foo` and `/foo/bar`.

(of course, there are still issues, in so far as we don't have a mechanism to return both the updated copy of `/foo` *and* the updated copy of `/bar` in a single response.  So instead we need to look into other ideas, like server push).

Answer (score 1):

Design the URL paths in a way that the resources can easily be retrieved.

Query string/parameter present in the URL mentioned in the first approach is typically used to locate a resource and perhaps a little counter intuitive to me.

The second approach, perhaps this would work as you are creating an expedition under an associated record xxx i.e. `/records/xxx/expeditions`. But it could get challenging in a scenario where an expedition is not related to any record.

Another alternative thought here is to link the expedition and record through the payload i.e. have the record id XXX within the POST payload during the "expedition" resource creation. `POST /expedition` => This operation would return you an expedition id in response as the resource newly gets created. To retrieve the data, you could then use `GET /expedition/XXX/record` where XXX is the expedition id and you retrieve the record corresponding to XXX. You don't need to mention a record id in this case. You either get a associated record or you don't(in case there is no record tied to the expedition). To retrieve the expedition itself, the URL could be `GET /expedition/XXX`.